# Visual studio code not finding Python modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-module

I have activated my venv in the terminal, I have insured that Pillow is installed and checked that I have the right Python interpreter selected in VSCode I am still getting these errors.

```
(env) PS C:\Users\Pixel\Projects\Python\DiceDistributionV2> python -u "c:\Users\Pixel\Projects\Python\DiceDistributionV2\main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Pixel\Projects\Python\DiceDistributionV2\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
(env) PS C:\Users\Pixel\Projects\Python\DiceDistributionV2> pip list
Package       Version
------------- -------
customtkinter 5.0.2
darkdetect    0.7.1
Pillow        9.4.0
pip           22.0.4
setuptools    58.1.0
```

Any idea what I can try next?

Comment: What does `python -m pip list` list?

Answer (score 0):

Please see your terminal command

```
(env) PS C:\Users\Pixel\Projects\Python\DiceDistributionV2> python -u "c:\Users\Pixel\Projects\Python\DiceDistributionV2\main.py"
```

Obviously you're using **Code Runner** to execute the script, if you're using the [**Python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension the command would be something like this:

[image]

Selecting an interpreter is a feature of **Python** extensions, so what interpreter you choose will not affect **Code Runner**.

Please use the official extension **Python** to run the script and you will get correct results.

[image]

***PS**: You can use the following code to verify the interpreter used by **Code Runner***

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

[image]

As shown in the picture above, I selected the `python3.11`, but **Code Runner** still uses the `python3.10` interpreter.

**Python** extension has no problem.

[image]

*If you still get the error, make sure you are using the **correct interpreter** (the one with `Pillow` installed). Or use the above code to output the full path of the interpreter, and then use the python command of the full path to install the `Pillow` package for the current interpreter.*